# Allowing a title bar double click to maximize a dialog but without max-min buttons

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

This is a little C# specific. The default behaviour of a resizable dialog box is that a title bar click maximizes the dialog and a second double click restores the size. However, what I want is to have the Help button turned on, which means the minimize and maximize buttons are hidden, but I would still like the title bar double click behaviour. This might be achievable with some subclassing, but perhaps someone has some good ideas on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private const int WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0xA3;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK:
                if (this.WindowState==System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized)
                    this.WindowState=System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal;
                else if (this.WindowState == System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Normal)
                    this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
                return;
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to handle the WM_NCHITTEST and look for HT_CAPTION, see *[WM_NCHITTEST message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645618(VS.85).aspx)* for details.

You'll need to override the WndProc to be able to handle these messages, this is demonstrated in *[Control.WndProc Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.wndproc(VS.71).aspx)*.

Comment: Thanks, that helped, except that it needed to be replaced by WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK

Comment: That is assuming of course that your user hasn't switched the buttons...I'm not sure if the OS would then see a right click but post the WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK message.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;

    // Let Windows drag this form for us
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch (m.Msg)
        {
            case WM_NCHITTEST:
                m.Result = (IntPtr)2;   // HTCLIENT
                return;
        }

        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```